# What is wrong with this block declaration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, objective-c-blocks

This is how I declare my completion block as a property:

```
typedef void(^completionBlock)(NSManagedObjectID *companyID, NSError *error);
@property (strong, nonatomic) completionBlock block;
```

When calling it with

```
self.completionBlock(self.company.objectID,self.error)
```

from within a method I get a compiler error in Xcode:

```
Too many arguments to block call, expected 0, have 2
```

What Did I miss?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isnt `block` the variable here? so you should be going `self.block(self.company.objectID,self.error)`

Comment: Cool, that was the answer! Thank you!

Comment: It seems that I am overworked :-) Thank you very much for your quick answer!